# How do you get last 3 residential floors?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have all residential floors but can't buy wookie arms, csilla apts, or endor arms.  Does anyone have these, and if so, how did you accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

I know that Wookie Arms can only be obtained as a rare reward in a salvage mission to Kashyyyk.

Csilla apts is from Csilla, and Endor Arms is from Endor, they are rare rewards if you do the missions.